# React Native Event Emitter between components

Tags: events, react-native

I have two components in react native. One class name is firstClass, and the second class is secondClass. "secondClass" is a child view of firstClass. I can submit my data to my firebase from the child view, but on successful submit, I want the view to go back to "firstClass".

I have used event emitters in the past, but those were only using navigatorIOS.

My question is, does the event emitter system listen to global events, or just within their class? And if so, how do I communicate from "secondClass" to "firstClass", that I want to show "firstClass" again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback function and call it from the second component :

in the first component:

```
//Constructor 
   ....
   this.state ={
      renderSecondComponent:false
   }
   ....
...Your code 
{
   this.renderSecondComponent()
}

renderSecondComponent(){
   if(this.state.renderSecondComponent){
      return(
         <SecondComponent callback={()=>{this.setState({renderSecondComponent:false})}}/>
      )
   }
}
```

In the second component

```
....Your code 
// when you should go back to the first component 
if(this.props.callback){
  this.props.callback()
}
```

Comment: Oh thats great! I'm still fairly new to react native. So I don't have to use the event emitter system for callbacks like Nodejs uses? I can just use callback function like in your example to communicate between child and parent components?

Comment: yes, it depend on what situation you have. In the above situation you can resolve it using a callback function only.

Comment: Awesome. Hope to know more like you some day so I can help people!

Comment: Kind of a another question of top of this one, I am passing a callback function to my child component and it works. However, what if I want to pass in a variable from my child component through the callback as a argument. Is this possible?

Comment: yes just pass it in second component and edit the function declaration and add your params

Comment: Well super, that was easy, thanks! Here is my code for anyone else who may be here.

Parent Component --> <Component callback={(foo) => this.doFunction(foo)} />

Child Component --> <TouchableHighlight onPress= {() => this.props.callback(argument)}>

Then in my parent I have a function called 'doFunction(foo)' that I can then use the new data from the child. Thanks again!

Comment: This is not correct ans. He is asking about event emitters not callbacks